# How to tell sphinx to ignore the 'include' directive when building documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx

I run sphinx-build command from the command line to build both latex and html documentation, since they have the same source .rst files:

`$ sphinx-build -b html <source> <output>`

`$ sphinx-build -b latex <source> <output>`

However, for the latex output I want to ignore all the "include" directives.

This can be done by adding a docutils.conf file in the same directory as the conf.py of sphinx with the following content:

```
[parsers]
[restructuredtext parser]
file-insertion-enabled:false
```

This is a partial solution though, since I have to change the content (false or true) of the docutils.conf file every time I run the sphinx-build for both html and latex outputs.

It is possible to tell sphinx to ignore the 'include' directive without relying on docutils.conf file, specifying that I want `no-file-insertion` when running the `sphinx-build` command?

Comment: Would https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html do the job?

Comment: Yes, after including the ifconfig sphinx extension, adding the ifconfig directive (wherever there is an include directive), and adding a custom config value within conf.py... I can call sphinx-build and tell it to ignore (or not) the include directive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some time searching, I found a sphinx directive that include its content only when a expression is true (the `only` directive):

```
.. only:: html

    .. include:: <path/to/file.rst>
```

This was a simple solution that works fine for me; the contents of `file.rst` are only included when making html documentation and not when making latex files.

Thanks!